# Adding pip libraries in pyinstaller to create an exe file for my script

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I am able to run my exe file but my scripts has multiple pip libraries for it to work. I always get this error when running my script.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 870, in run
  File "AIO_Bot.py", line 265, in main_function
  File "cloudscraper/__init__.py", line 665, in create_scraper
  File "cloudscraper/__init__.py", line 120, in __init__
  File "cloudscraper/user_agent/__init__.py", line 20, in __init__
  File "cloudscraper/user_agent/__init__.py", line 77, in loadUserAgent
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/8g/gkf53znx7_7405c26w344ftw0000gn/T/_MEIujM2ll/cloudscraper/user_agent/browsers.json'
Finished in 0.0 second(s)
```

If anyone knows how to fix this please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your browswers.json is expected to be found in a relative path from the "exe" (cloudscraper/user_agent) when it is not the case when it is really a exe file. You have to modify your pyinstaller build command to include that file in the package. Add
--add-data '/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudscraper/user_agent/browsers.json:cloudscraper/user_agent' and it should work. (replace : with ; on Windows)

You can refer to https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your script/exe is looking for a file named "browsers.json".
Locate it and try putting it in the same folder as your created *.exe

Comment: How can I locate it then add it properly?

Comment: ok, let us step back: Your py-script which should be an *exe works?This would mean there is a browsers.json somewhere around.If it is from a module then try to follow the hints from Seaver Olson. If it is a file which is generated by yourself then you need it also with the *.exe

Comment: It is from cloudscraper module.

Answer (score 0):

The file is not being located because you are searching through a path that can not be opened.  If your script is on the same level of the path then you would only have to do this

```
(browsers.json)
```

to fix this just exclude the directory path

```
mv /lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudscraper/user_agent/browsers.json /var/folders/8g/gkf53znx7_7405c26w344ftw0000gn/T/_MEIujM2ll/cloudscraper/user_agent/
```

if this does not work pip install cloudscraper in terminal instead because pycharms assigniing the file to it's own enviroment

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: instead of calling browsers.json like /var/folders/8g/gkf53znx7_7405c26w344ftw0000gn/T/_MEIujM2ll/cloudscraper/user_agent/browsers.json call it just /browsers.json

Comment: if that does not make sense please post more of the code so I can explain it better.

Comment: How can I just call it /browser.json? Also I used pyinstaller in pycharm and used the terminal in pycharm to create the exe file. Do you think I need to locate the path to find /browser.json? And that is all the error code it gave.

Comment: @jjboi8708 I looked further into the error and I think your module might be broken try to use pip3 install cloudscraper --upgrade

Comment: Where would I do that? In the pycharm terminal?

Comment: @jjboi8708 yes.

Comment: Then i would delete Cloudscraper and redownload it, the problem is that browsers.json does not exist so the file is either in the wrong path or does not exist

Comment: I searched for the browsers.json on my mac and it is in the pycharm folder /lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudscraper/user_agent. So how would I make it so that it creates that path? I made a whole new environment and tried it again but it still has that error.

Comment: please let me know if that fixes your problem

Comment: Nvm I got it to work using cx_Freeze. Thanks for the help tho!